# Nifi failed to write to FileSystemRepository Stream

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a flow where I am using the getFile processor. The input directory is a network mount point. When I test the flow on small files (les than 1GB), it works well. When I test it on bigger files (more than 1GB), I get the following error :

> GetFile[id=f1a533fd-1959-16d3-9579-64e64fab1ac6] Failed to retrieve
>   files due to
>   org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.FlowFileAccessException: Failed to
>   import data from /path/to/directory for
>   StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=f8389032-c6f5-43b9-a0e3-7daab3fa115a,claim=,offset=0,name=490908299598990,size=0]
>   due to java.io.IOException: Failed to write to FileSystemRepository
>   Stream [StandardContentClaim
>   [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1486976827205-28,
>   container=default, section=28], offset=0, length=45408256]]

Do you have any idea about the origin of this error ?

Thank you for your answers

Comment: What type of disk do you have available for your content repository? How much space is available? What throughput are you expecting? Did you change the configurations as described in [Configuration Best Practices](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#configuration-best-practices)?

Comment: I'd also suggest there is more available in the log file most likely regarding that IoException and if so it would likely be very telling.

Comment: Hi Andy, Joe, I have barely some Gigabytes available for all my repositories (content repository, flowfile repository, provenance repository, ...). For now I am testing the flows on a single file, so no big throughput is expected. Is there any requiremements on the size of the content repository ? as for the logs I looked for errors on nifi.app.log but didn't find any reference to the error I was getting on the UI. Is there another file where I should look ? Thnak you for your suggestions.

Comment: Hey Mohammed, have you found the solution for this one?

Comment: Hi Roman, yes, the problem was as suggested by Andy the size of content repositories. Those repos are used as temporary storage space for flowfiles. So extending the size of repos solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments the answer in this specific case was found by Andy and confirmed by the asker:

The content repositories were too small in proportion to the file size.

Another thing to look at for future readers is whether the memory of the Nifi node is large enough to hold individual messages.

Answer (score 1):

Although the answer provided by Dennis is correct at analysing the root cause, there is not a solution for it, so let me provide one.

## Answer/Solution for Containers

Since you can't specify a size for a docker `volume`, we can't use them for this task if you are lacking the required space for your flowfiles content.

Instead, I recommend using `bind mounts`. This way, you could use up to (theoretically) all your machine disk.

```
# Create a folder where to locate the NiFi Flowfiles content in the host
mkdir -p /tmp/data/nifi/nifi-data-content_repository
```

Then, modify your `docker-compose.yml` file to modify the type of storage to be used. Specifically, you have to look for the contents repository volume:

```
- type: source
  source: nifi-data-content_repository
  target: /opt/nifi/nifi-current/content_repository
```

And replace it with the bind mount targeting the folder that we've just created above:

```
- type: bind
  source: /tmp/data/nifi/nifi-data-content_repository
  target: /opt/nifi/nifi-current/content_repository
```

Ready, now you can re-deploy your NiFi with this mount capable of using your host disk space.

Read more on bind mounts in the [official docs](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/).

Comment: I usually don't say this, but as you explicitly mentioned my answer to be correct: Usually that would be accompanied by an upvote so others may see it being correct as well ;-)
Though this answer is perhaps not exactly what was asked, I do believe it can help future visitors so will upvote as well.